# Keycloak says it imports users but they don't show up

Tags: keycloak, openldap

I've setup keycloak to import users from an openldap server.  As a test run, I went with the default h2 to see if I could get it running.  It connects and authenticates correctly.  Once I hit synchronize all users, it reports back Success x imported users, 0 changed users.  After going into Manage=>Users and clicking on View all Users, it only shows a generic Username user with the email user@user.com.
The only information I get from server.log is the warning message below.

I'm not sure what direction to look for how to fix this.  Is there some sort of other place I should look for an error message or some other thing I should try?

2018-12-19 15:56:31,209 WARN  [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.InfinispanChangelogBasedTransaction] (default task-7) Not present cache item for key LoginFailureKey [ realmId=namis. userId=14ed02d1-3ac3-4911-a377-80863f2bde70 ]

Update:

---

I checked the user_entity table after import and the users are there.  Once I go to Manage Users, the users from the realm disappear from the database.

I turned on trace level logging and found the error message 
[org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager] (default task-1) Removed invalid user 'John Doe'

I searched through the source code and found the function,importValidation, that calls the function which removes the user.  This seems to happen when a storage provider is null or validate is called on  a user and realm and it returns a null UserModel.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had one of the mappers incorrect.  The username mapper was not mapped to the correct ldap attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue today and it's possible to just remove the username mapper altogether, as the username attribute is already mapped from Username LDAP attribute in User Federation settings.